# How can I get `ds` in SlackAPIPostOperator?

Tags: airflow

I want to run a python script which need a datetime param and post its output to slack. But I don't know how to get airflow template variable `ds`.

Let's say, I have below code:

```
def make_txt():
    # get ds
    ds = get_ds()
    ds = ds * 3 + 4 / 5   # do something with ds
    return ds

slack_task = SlackAPIPostOperator(
    text=make_txt(),
    token='xoxp-xxxxxxx',
)
```

Because I will run with `airflow backfill dag_id -s 2016-10-01`, the `ds` (here is 2016-10-01) should pass to slack text.

I try to write python script output to a file and then read it and pass to slack text directly. But I don't think that's a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `text` field of `SlackAPIPostOperator` is templated, so if you add `{{ ds }}` somewhere within the text it will be inserted by jinja.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the {{ ds }} for some python operator, it may pass to some function. I think this question has no answer about that.

Comment: Within the PythonOperator you can specify `provide_context=True`, add a `**kwargs` to the function you call and then you can access it via `kwargs['ds']`. Note that if you're trying to access `ds` within the DAG definition itself, that's not really possible.